# Test front-end application without back-end

Tags: javascript, mocking, xmlhttprequest

My web application uses `XMLHttpRequest` to load JSON data returned by a backend server running PHP. It then renders the result in the browser using a client-side Javascript templating library.

```
function load(src) {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onload = function () {
        _this.data = JSON.parse(oReq.responseText);
        _this.render(_this.data);
    };
    oReq.open('get', src, opts.async || true);
    oReq.send();    
}
load('article.php?page=1&lang=en');
load('userprofile.php?userid=1548&lang=en');
```

The real backend API `article.php` is not ready.
I want to simulate/mock the response of `article.php?page=1&lang=en`
**in order to make an end to end test or to demonstrate the application**.

How can I change the behaviour of XMLHttpRequest (or mock it) so that **it won't open a HTTP connection**, but returns pre-configured data according to each request? The mock should simulate a slow connection (delay 1 sec before returning the response) and also support timeout (as the normal XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: @dave I don't want to maintain a local test PHP server, It is the test for frontend, I prefer to keep all the fake data maintain by the frontend team, and as a specs for backend PHP team

Comment: I haven't tried it but looks promising http://sinonjs.org/

Comment: what's your testing framework? using jasmine you can use .callFake

Comment: @BirgitMartinelle Not for unit test, but rather an end to end test, or a demonstration, to show how the website is rendering with the fake json data. I have to fake many REST API coming from internal + external service in order to make (offline localhost) demonstration of my front-end application

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: [sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server) is the right answer

Here an example to show how we can fake a RESTful server which is capable of respond to some specific ajax requests of application (other requests will call the real service)

https://gist.github.com/duongphuhiep/f4c807309a25906fc1c1

---

ok, I think this is the answer

https://github.com/philikon/MockHttpRequest

This library replace the XMLHttpRequest with a mock object. So I won't need to refactor or change the existing codes.

In this example: I faked the response coming from `backend/blog.php?page=1&lang=fr`

https://gist.github.com/duongphuhiep/b36a7fffa3fec7d955ac

However, I did not successfully simulate the timeout due to network latency.